# why does the error regarding gcc is occuring in matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, visual-studio-2012, mex

I have download that code from [github](https://github.com/kopepod/ADCSF?).
 Whenever that code tries to check mexopencv (a file inside lib folder). It shows an error on `Matlab 2017a` that is:

```
[error 3] please make sure gcc >= 4.4 g++ >= 4.4 is installed ...
```

I am having a gcc version of `8.8.0`

Following is the description of system

- Window 10
- Visual Studio 2012
- Matlab 2017a
- opencv 2.4.10
- mexopencv (install from your folder LIB)

Answer (score 0):

You might lack of standard libraries (.dll in Windows but .lib in Linux). The code was developed under Linux (help is also only provided for Linux systems) and once tested under Windows 7.

> The method was tested under OS linux lubuntu 14.04, CPU intel i5 and
>   16GB of RAM. This guide was written under a linux-based distribution
>   scope, more precisely debian. Unfortunately we lack experience to
>   address bugs or any problem that could emerge in non-linux OS, we will
>   provide only linux OS help regarding execution problems, we apologise.
>   we tested this code on Windows7. We successfully installed opencv
>   2.4.10 following this tutorial: [http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/]

This suggests that the mex-function is also linux-based. The error should vanish if you compile the source code yourself on your system, e.g. with MinGW (also GCC), see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html).

**EDITED:**
the README.markdown file (under *LIB/mexopencv-master.zip*) provides a little guide through the installation process of both, openCV and the mexopencv function for unix (including ubuntu 14.04) and Windows systems. The latter states:

> Browse to mexopencv root folder, and type the following in the MATLAB
>   command window:
>
> ```
> >> mexopencv.make
> ```
>
> By default, mexopencv assumes the OpenCV library is installed in
>   `C:\opencv`. If this is not the case, specify the path as an argument:
>
> ```
> >> mexopencv.make('opencv_path', 'c:\your\path\to\opencv')
> ```
>
> Note that if you build OpenCV from source, this path specification
>   might not work out of the box. You need to replace dll files in the
>   OpenCV package with newly built binaries. Or, you need to modify
>   `+mexopencv/make.m` to correctly link your MEX-files with the library.
>
> To remove existing mexopencv binaries, use the following command.
>
> ```
> >> mexopencv.make('clean', true)
> ```

It requires a standard C++ compiler supported by Matlab ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html)), any Visual Studio installation should be OK, as an open-source option MinGW is recommended. Just remember to pick the right system (usually 64-bit).

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 as a compiler, so do I need to install MinGW?

Comment: Is there any method to install gcc>=4.4?

Comment: check out the README.markdown. You need a standard C++ compiler (VS2012 is OK). The readme guides you through the installation of openCV (probably not necessary for you) and how to build the `mexopencv` file. I will edit the answer to include it

Comment: Thanks for adding the edit part. The commands you have mentioned in edit part are working fine on the system. The issue arose when system create build with 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C).I am having an issue related to gcc & g++ commands. The system display error in this form                                     
ERROR:                                                                                                                 
'creating mex HOF ...
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 (C)'.
[error 3] please make sure gcc >= 4.4 g++ >= 4.4 is installed'

Comment: @TariqS check again that you have Matlab 2017a since it is the last version that supports *Microsoft Visual C++ 2012* **Professional** https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/previous-releases.html and check the setup `mex -setup -v` to see what compiler was set to use in matlab

Comment: @TariqS use the `@` to notify me directly and don't forget to give credit eventually